# Disposing of objects with circular references

Tags: python, with-statement, circular-reference, contextmanager

My design is as follows:

- `__main__` references `a`
- `a` references `b`
- `b` references `a`
- `a` is created and then disposed of from `__main__`

Thus `a` and `b` have circular references. However upon `del a` I would prefer both `a` and `b` disposed of.

I see in many places advice to use Context Managers, and specifically the `with` statement instead of `__del__()`. However all the examples I see of `with` start and end in local scope (e.g. of a certain method)

Can this be elegantly performed with `with`?
What is the alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend either:

- Using [weakref](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html) - which is sometimes applicable when circular references are involved
- or ... just manually disposing of stuff in the order you need - not in `__del__` but in an explicit `dispose` method *you* call at the right time(s)

In general, when you know you have circular references, relying on automatic `__del__` disposal is not a good idea. It's brittle - even if you manage to make it work in some case, small changes in dependencies can break it again.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the alternative?

Do nothing.  Until you create millions of circular references like this -- and can prove that this (and only this) is breaking your program -- it doesn't actually matter.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collector is supposed to handle this.